# Creating A New Table from An Existing Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table

Within MS SQL Server, I am looking to create a new table from an existing table. My existing table is dbo.AmtrakROAS and I would like my new table to be called WeeklyROAS. I suspect the issue is related to a quirk of MS SQL Server and how you generate new tables within it.

Here is my existing code:

```
Create Table WeeklyROAS

Select * into AmtrakROAS
From WeeklyROAS
```

**Picture of the code and ERROR**
[image]

Comment: `Create Table WeeklyROAS` is spurious and unnecessary, also you have `INTO` and `FROM` table backwards

Comment: @Charlieface I found the solution but why you would the  Create Table WeeklyROAS is unnecessary? How would I have been able to reference  a table called WeeklyRoas if I never created one.

Comment: `SELECT ... INTO WeeklyROAS` creates the table. Otherwise you need `CREATE TABLE WeeklyROAS (Column1...` and `INSERT WeeklyROAS (Column1... SELECT ...`